# Motioneyeos Download Help

Tags: camera, pi-3b+, software-installation, image

Does anyone know of a way to download motioneyeos without using Win32DiskImager or Etcher? I am trying to download motioneyeos using a raspberry pi, and can't find a way to use a disk imager. Does anyone know of a place where i can just download the pre-imaged files? I am using a RPI 3 B+

Thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Why don't you run a Raspbian OS and install motion there? What's your objective with the MotionEyeOS?

Comment: Hi! I am putting this on a shelf to monitor to see if anyone takes something. I have heard that this can detect motion then record video. Is it possible to download motioneyeos into raspbian?

Comment: Yes, you can run motion simply on Raspbian.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know of a way to download motioneyeos without using
>   Win32DiskImager or Etcher?

Download this file - [motioneyeos-raspberrypi3-20190911.img.xz](https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos/releases/download/20190911/motioneyeos-raspberrypi3-20190911.img.xz) then follow procedure of this link: [MotionEyeOS Installation](https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos/wiki/Installation).

---

> Is it possible to download motioneyeos into raspbian?

Yes. Follow the procedure:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install motion
sudo service motion start
```

It will download approximately 70MB and try to install that. Take note that all configuration you can find and config is in `/etc/motion/motion.conf`. You can change some default sections and open this URL `http://raspberrypi:8080` on other hosts. More description of the configuration is [here](https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html).

If you want to check the real-time logs, stop service by running `sudo service motion stop` and then fire this command:

```
sudo motion
```